# Class.forName is giving ClassNotFound Exception

Tags: java

I am using the following code ::

```
String className  = "SmsHelper"
Class c = Class.forName(className);
```

And I am getting the following

stackTrace ::

```
 inside main java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: SmsURLHelper
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at com.tcs.sms.actions.SmsUtil.invoke(SmsUtil.java:131)
```

Note : The SmsHelper class is present.

Please suggest if I have missed any thing.

Comment: Which is the real, fully qualified name of the class? `SmsHelper`, `SmsURLHelper`, or `com.foo.bar.SmsURLHelper`?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Use the fully qualified name.

Example:

```
Class.forName("com.yourownpackage.SmsHelper");
```

Answer (score 4):

Please write the Class name along with its package name(in which your class resides) as a String in the **forName** method. Here is the sample to use:

```
String className  = "com.testpackage.SmsHelper";
Class c = Class.forName(className);
```

Answer (score 4):

1. `class.forName()` expects a fully qualified class name -- such as `com.tcs.foo.bar.SmsURLHelper`.
2. Why not just write `SmsHelper.class` -- that will be checked at compile time, compiled to an appropriate call to class.forName().

Comment: I know this is super old, but this was the best solution. I needed the class name as a string so I just used `SmsHelper.class.getName()`. No reason to figure out the fully qualified one myself.